# How to plot the derivative of an interpolation function?

Tags: plotting

Consider the simple case:

```
sol = NDSolve[{f'[x] == x, f[0] == 1}, f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

If I want to plot it I just use:

```
Plot[f[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}]
```

But how do I plot the derivative `f'[x]`?

Comment: See the first three code examples under "Basic Examples" in [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define

```
F[x_] = f[x] /. sol[[1]]
```

and now you can use `F[x]` and `F'[x]`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend using function syntax, note the missing `[x]` after `f` in second argument:

```
sol = NDSolve[{f'[x] == x, f[0] == 1}, f, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: interpolating function]

Then it would be easy to get this:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], f'[x]} /. sol], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot of function and derivative]